# defiant.js support in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using this plugin defiant.js in my code. But IE11 is not supporting this plugin.

I am seeing this error :
**Object doesn't support property or method 'selectNodes' File: defiant.min.js**

I could not find proper solution. 
What I learnt from studying this problem is this is somewhat related to Xpath calculations, and that is not supported properly in IE.

Please guide me, I have tried to go through all the related questions but could not find the one which can help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!
(Apologies, if anyone finds this Q is duplicate; in case please share the corresponding answer link. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the plugin defiant.js. The problem is with the Xpath evaluation support under IE 10, 11.
Before IE10, xpath evaluation is supported through msxml documents.
The detailed and well explained information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e), you can find solutions as well.

I hope that helps to solve your problem.

Comment: That helped me to solve the issue. I will update my question with answer soon.